# Connect to WSL2 Postgres database from local network

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

I run Postgres 12 service in Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2).

In my `/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`, I have:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

while my `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf` has this content:

```
local   all    postgres                 peer

local   all    all                      peer
host    all    all         0.0.0.0/0    md5
host    all    all         ::0/0        md5

host    all    all         0.0.0.0/0    md5
host    all    all         ::0/0        md5
host    all    all         all          md5
```

If I try to connect to this server from any other device then the local machine, it times out.

Does anyone have any idea why should this be?

Comment: That's a firewall. You are not planning to use that platform for anything serious where you would mind losing data, right?

Comment: yep, just for home testing

Comment: Good, because as far as I know it is not safe for databases.

Comment: I additionally opened the port 5432 in windows firewall, but same result

Comment: If the connection times out, that is a network problem and has nothing to do with the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward Windows port to WSL2.

> When using a WSL 1 distribution, if your computer was set up to be accessed by your LAN, then applications run in WSL could be accessed on your LAN as well.
>
> This isn't the default case in WSL 2. **WSL 2 has a virtualized ethernet adapter with its own unique IP address. Currently, to enable this workflow you will need to go through the same steps as you would for a regular virtual machine.** (We are looking into ways to improve this experience.)
>
> Here's an example PowerShell command to add a port proxy that listens on port 4000 on the host and connects it to port 4000 to the WSL 2 VM with IP address 192.168.101.100.
>
> ```
> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4000 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=4000 connectaddress=192.168.101.100
> ```

<sub>***Reference** : [Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2 : Accessing a WSL 2 distribution from your local area network (LAN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan) (Microsoft | Docs)*</sub>

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE. Always consider adding the relevant information, as link only answers are normally deleted. Links tend to expire and then the answer becomes a non-answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just in case someone else was looking for a current link to the same information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-a-wsl-2-distribution-from-your-local-area-network-lan